# Attribute Error. Can not access attributes in Class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to call a class Pager in my main function in Python. When I run the program it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "lab4.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()   File "lab4.py", line 34, in main
    demandPager.processRef(p, clock, rand)   File "/Users/kiranbhimani/Desktop/OSLab4/Pager.py", line 16, in processRef
    desiredPage = Pager.frameTable.findPageById(testId, process.getProcessId()) 

**AttributeError: class Pager has no attribute 'frameTable'**
```

How can I access frameTable? If I insert "self" as a parameter, I can't call the class. It says processRef requires 4 arguments but only 3 are given.

I'm not sure what is going on here. Thank you in advance!

```
class Pager:
def __init__(self, machineSize, pageSize):
    self.machineSize = machineSize
    self.pageSize = pageSize
    self.frameTable = FrameTable(int(machineSize/pageSize))

@staticmethod 
def processRef(process, clock, randreader):
    ref = int(process.currentReference)
    testId = int(ref / Page.size)
    #print Pager.machineSize
    desiredPage = Pager.frameTable.findPageById(testId, process.getProcessId())
    if (isHit(desiredPage, process)):       
        desiredPage.addRefdWord(ref)

    else:
        if (not frameTable.isFull()):
            frameTable.addPage(process, testId, ref)

        else:
            pageToEvict = findPageToReplace(replacementAlgo, randreader)
            frameTable.evictPage(pageToEvict)
            frameTable.addPage(process, testId, ref)
            desiredPage = frameTable.lastPageAdded

        desiredPage = frameTable.lastPageAdded
        desiredPage.setIfLoaded(true)
        process.incrNumPageFaults()


    desiredPage.timeLastUsed = clock
    frameTable.updateTimes()
```

This is the main function:

```
from Process import Process
from Page import Page as Page
from Pager import Pager
from FrameTable import FrameTable 
import sys

runningProcesses = []
finishedProcesses = []
def main():
    #read input
    machineSize = int(sys.argv[1])
    pageSize = int(sys.argv[2])
    processSize = int(sys.argv[3])
    jobMix = int(sys.argv[4])
    numOfRefPerProcess = int(sys.argv[5])
    replacementAlgo = (sys.argv[6])
    demandPager = Pager(machineSize, pageSize)
    Page.size = pageSize
    Process.size = processSize
    setProc(jobMix)
    demandPager.replacementAlgo = replacementAlgo

    index = 0
    clock = 0
    while(len(runningProcesses) > 0):
        p = runningProcesses[index]
        for i in range(3):
            demandPager.processRef(p, clock, rand)
            p.setCurrentReference(p.calcNextReference(rand))
            p.incrRefsMade()

            clock+=1

            if (p.getRefsMade() == numRefPerProcess):
                finishedProcesses.add(p)
                runningProcesses.remove(p)
                index-=1
                break
        if (index == numProcesses-1):
            index = 0
        else:
            index+=1
    print "printing....."
    printOutput(args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to access a class property `frameTable`, but this class has no added properties at all.  *Objects* of the class have properties of `machineSize`, `FrameSize`, and `pageTable` -- that's one of each for every object you instantiate.

For instance, there will be a `demandPager.frameTable` once you hit the creation command, but you haven't given any properties (other than the built-ins) to `Pager` as a class.

Perhaps you want to use `self`

```
desiredPage = self.frameTable.findPageById(testId, process.getProcessId())
```

Comment: This is the error I get if I add "self" as a parameter:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab4.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File "lab4.py", line 34, in main
    demandPager.processRef(p, clock, rand)
TypeError: processRef() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Right.  You need to change all of your references to be consistent.  `self` is an implied argument to all class methods, but must appear explicitly in the function profile (the `def` line).